# API to get the preferred block size of a DMG

Tags: macos, cocoa, unix, filesystems

If I mount a DMG on my Mac and then use the IORegistryExplorer, I can see the preferred block size is 0x200.

What API can I use to obtain this same information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `FSGetVolumeInfo` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSGetVolumeInfo) to request [the allocation-block information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kFSVolInfoBlocks) for any mounted volume. One of the three fields that that includes is the block size.